# Have two non identical list of dictionaries and need to merge them with a non unique key

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

```
d1 = [{'del':True, 'Name':'tbl_n','node':'3'},{'del':True, 'Name':'src_n','node':'5'}]
d2 = [{'items':'23', 'column_name':'tbl_n','created':'3.34','count':0,'valid':'yes'},
{'items':'43', 'column_name':'src_n','created':'3.34','count':40,'valid':'yes'},
{'items':'22', 'column_name':'mod_n','created':'3.34','count':13,'valid':'no'}
```

I would like to merge d1 to d2 with respect to 'Name' key in d1 and 'column_name' in d2

below is one of the tried step

```
from collections import Counter
summed = sum((Counter({elem['column_name']: elem['val_count']}) for elem in my_dict1 + my_dict2), Counter())
print(summed)
```

the expected output im looking for is

```
d3 = [{'items':23, 'Name': 'tbl_n','node':3,'created':3.34,'count':0,'valid':'yes'},{'del':True,'items':43,'Name':'src_n','node':5.'created':3.34,'count':40,'valid':'yes'},{'items':22,'column_name:'mod_n','created':3.34,'count':14,'valid':'no'}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could include a sample of the output you are looking for.

Comment: What non unique key is the title referring to?

Comment: Did you forget `del: True` in the first element of `d3`?

Comment: Your code appears to be completely unrelated to the desired output, so please be **very** precise about your merging behavior. Doing so will also help you come up with your own solution.

Comment: key 1 is column_name and key 2 is 'val_count' the code i have written may be irrelevant but im trying to come up with something relevant. thanks for your comments

Answer (score 0):

I tried to understand your expected output and suggest you the following solution. Tell me if you expect something else. Regarding your code, I replaced `d1`and `d2` identifiers with respectively `ld1`and `ld2` ('ld' being for 'list of dictionaries') for better readability:

```
ld1 = [{'del':True, 'Name':'tbl_n','node':'3'},
       {'del':True, 'Name':'src_n','node':'5'}]

ld2 = [{'items':'23', 'column_name':'tbl_n','created':'3.34','count':0, 'valid':'yes'},
       {'items':'43', 'column_name':'src_n','created':'3.34','count':40,'valid':'yes'},
       {'items':'22', 'column_name':'mod_n','created':'3.34','count':13,'valid':'no'}]


def mergeTwoListOfDicts(ld1, ld2):

    result = []

    for d2 in ld2:
        for d1 in ld1:
            if ('Name' in d1) and ('column_name' in d2):
                if d1['Name'] == d2['column_name']:
                    d2.pop('column_name')
                    d2.update(d1)
                    break
        result.append(d2)

    return result


print(mergeTwoListOfDicts(ld1, ld2))
# [{'items': '23', 'created': '3.34', 'count': 0,  'valid': 'yes', 'del': True, 'Name': 'tbl_n', 'node': '3'},
#  {'items': '43', 'created': '3.34', 'count': 40, 'valid': 'yes', 'del': True, 'Name': 'src_n', 'node': '5'},
#  {'items': '22', 'created': '3.34', 'count': 13, 'valid': 'no', 'column_name': 'mod_n'}]
```

Comment: This is great Lauren, but the result does not contain the values of only one dict in my case. what am i missing.

Comment: This is not clear at all for me. Please provide more examples of inputs and expected outputs in your question.